# How do load value from DB only once in java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using spring boot application and want to load constant values from `DB` only once t avoid multiple `DB` calls. As i am using same constants multiple time in my application i am not using `Cashing` is there any alternatives to load only once.

```
 public class DBConstants {
   
   @Autowired
   DBService service;

   public static String WORD_LIMIT ;
   
   public loadOnce(){
      WORD_LIMIT = service.getWordLimit();
    }
  }
```

is this a right approach.

In my service `Aservice.java`

```
      if(empDto.getFirstName().length()>Integer.parseInt(DBConstants.WORD_LIMIT)){
         // some code and logic
      }
```

SImilar in `Bservice.java` etc

So idea is to make `DB call` only once.

Answer (score 0):

You may create a component with a private field and a public getter, in the getter implement the field check: if this is initialized just return otherwise load from DB, assign to the field and return. But using this approach you need check and initialize the value in synchronous code to make guarantee the DB call happens only once.

But I think to use a Spring cache is better solution.